# Bash variable not set when calling the script from wrapper binary

Tags: bash, variables, wrapper

I have the following codes,
the bash script "tryme.sh":

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH || /bin/kill $$)

PASS="hellthatrocks"

if [ ! -v "$1" ]; then
    echo "no.."
    echo "hell..."
    exit 1
fi

if test "$1" = "$PASS" ; then
    echo "yeah it is : $PASS"
else
    echo "humm..."
fi

exit 0
```

and the wrapper binary "wrapper.c":

```c++
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int arc, char** arv) {
    char *argv[] = { "/bin/bash", "-p", "./tryme.sh", arv[1] , NULL };
    execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

```bash
compiled gcc -o wrapper wrapper.c
export hellthatrocks="hellthatrocks"
```

The matter is when I give a pattern as a parameter that is looking for defined environment-variables in a command line like:

```bash
./tryme.sh ${!h*}
```

It gives me, "yeah it is `hellthatrocks`".

But if I call the script from the wrapper, it does not find the variable and gives "no... hell...."

```bash
./wrapper ${!h*}
```

What is going wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: `and gives "no... hell...."` What system are you on? `execve` should error... And why are you using `${!h*}` ? Why not plain `"hellthatrocks"`? And I hope you do know that your script does __not__ read the value of environment variable - so what is the point of setting it? Och, I see why it does not error, from [man execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), but quoting `Do not take advantage of this nonstandard and nonportable misfeature!`

Comment: no error... it works for Linux  5.4.0-62-generic #70~18.04.1-Ubuntu... wrapper gives no error. but it calls the script and the script can not find hellthatrocks... i checked every variable... it recognizes the hellthatrocks but can not determine if it was set so...

Comment: @hellXY Since you use execve, the orignal environment is replaced by empty one.

Comment: is there a way to read the password from the wrapper binary calling tryme.sh script ? Because both of them the script and the binary has the same user....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is going wrong ?

The `envp` may be incorrectly specified as `NULL` on linux, from the man page:

> On Linux, argv and envp can be specified as NULL.  In both cases,
> this has the same effect as specifying the argument as a pointer    to
> a list containing a single null pointer.  **Do not take    advantage of
> this nonstandard and nonportable misfeature!**

you specified it to `NULL`, so in the child process the environment is empty, so the exported `hellthatrocks` variable does not exists - so the check `[ -v "$1" ]` with`$1=hellthatrocks` fails.

Comment: thanks for explaining.. I voted this post as answer... Unfortunately, i can not upvote, because i have no 15 reputations. Sorry... I must post more often here to get in this business. once more thx...